# How to replace my power supply safely?

Tags: power-supply, power, cable, voltage

If something is powered from a 9 V and 1 A supply, you can replace it with a 9 V and 1 or more amp supply. How would one calculate if it is safe to replace it with a less voltage and less amperage supply, lets say,

Comment: More amps is ok, but not less, voltage needs to be within 1 volt .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a limit on how much more ampers can I supply for a laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/1316915/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-more-ampers-can-i-supply-for-a-laptop)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It has been asked many times before

Answer (score 2):

> How would one calculate if it is safe to replace it with a less voltage and less amperage supply

**do not do it**

You'd need to know specifications / test all components and need deep electric knowledge.

Comment: You can, sometimes, use a power supply with lesser amperage, with the approach above. However, it the original power supply is 9 volts, don't try to use a lesser power supply without confirming the voltage and amperage needed by every component AND whether any of those components are not getting power directly from the power supply input, but instead drawing power through another componet (which might step up or step down the voltage).